# Appending a slice to the end scala

Tags: scala

just wondering how to append a slice to the end of the slice IE  `val alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` `alpha.slice(13,26)` `"NOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` then add to `"ABCDEFGHIJKLM"` to produce `NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM`.

My teacher has asked us to produce Map[Int, string].
been stuck banging my head against the wall on this for a fair while
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple method:

```
(alpha + alpha).slice(13, 13+26)
```

See [the article referenced in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706319/how-do-you-rotate-circular-shift-of-a-scala-collection) for more efficient ways of doing this.

---

As a method this is

```
def rotateString(s: String, offset: Int): String =
  (s + s).slice(offset, offset + s.length)
```

Comment: In a testing situation how do you make that variable?
`Table(1).mkString should be ("BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA")` or
`Table(13).mkString should be ("NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM")`